# Connect to WEP/WPA without nmcli?

Tags: networking, wifi, nmcli

I'm facing an issue where `nmcli` stops working on a custom rockchip controller.

When running `nmcli dev wifi`, I get no results so I had to start using `iwlist scan`. Is there something similar for `nmcli d wifi connect`?

I keep getting back `No network with SSID '2KLIC Guests' found` with `nmcli`.

This is the script I want to replace:

```
if [ -n "$2" ];then
  nmcli d wifi connect "$1" password "$2"
else
  nmcli d wifi connect "$1"
fi
```

*Or maybe there is a command I can run to fix `nmcli` (it did return results at one point, seems it had its configurations changed while using AP mode).*

---

Results of `iwconfig wlan3`:

```
wlan3     unassociated  Nickname:"<WIFI@REALTEK>"
          Mode:Auto  Frequency=2.412 GHz  Access Point: Not-Associated   
          Sensitivity:0/0  
          Retry:off   RTS thr:off   Fragment thr:off
          Power Management:off
          Link Quality=0/100  Signal level=0 dBm  Noise level=0 dBm
          Rx invalid nwid:0  Rx invalid crypt:0  Rx invalid frag:0
          Tx excessive retries:0  Invalid misc:0   Missed beacon:0
```

Comment: Yes check out https://shapeshed.com/linux-wifi/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can connect through `wpa_supplicant` command , create a `wpa_supplicant.conf` file through `wpa_passphrase` command then connect:

```
touch /etc/wpa_supplicant/wpa_supplicant.conf
echo ctrl_interface=/run/wpa_supplicant > /etc/wpa_supplicant/wpa_supplicant.conf
echo update_config=1 >> /etc/wpa_supplicant/wpa_supplicant.conf
wpa_passphrase "Your_SSID" Your_PASSWORD >> /etc/wpa_supplicant/wpa_supplicant.conf
i=$(iw dev | grep Interface | awk '{ print $2}')
killall wpa_supplicant
wpa_supplicant -i $i -c/etc/wpa_supplicant/wpa_supplicant.conf -B
dhclient $i
```

A sample script may contain the following lines:

```
i=$(iw dev | grep Interface | awk '{ print $2}')
killall wpa_supplicant
wpa_supplicant -i $i -c/etc/wpa_supplicant/wpa_supplicant.conf -B
dhclient $i
```

The `killall wpa_supplicant` is added because you are using network-manager , it will create a wpa_supplicant instance.

Also you can connect through `wpa_supplicant` using a WEP key.

Create a `wpa_supplicant.conf` manually (`wpa_passphrase` will not work to generate a conf file) , e,g:

```
ctrl_interface=/run/wpa_supplicant
update_config=1

network={
    ssid="YOUR-SSID"
    key_mgmt=NONE
    wep_key0="12345"
    wep_tx_keyidx=0
}
```

Or simply you can connect through :

```
iwconfig <interface> essid "Your_SSID" key WEP_KEY
```

or:

```
iw dev <interface> connect "Your_SSID" key 0:WEP_KEY
```

The `wpa_cli` command line tool (recommanded by [@dirkt](https://unix.stackexchange.com/users/193028/dirkt)) is also an alternative to `nmcli` , you can use the interactive mode by typing `wpa_cli` or directly by:

```
wpa_cli -p/var/run/wpa_supplicant OPTION
```

The `OPTION` can be : `scan` ; `scan_results` , `add_network 0` ..... see `man wpa_cli` and `wpa_cli --help` for more details.

Comment: Thanks, I can't test right now but I will asap. I assume this solution will fail on WEP?

Comment: Wpa_supplicant support WEP ; WPA and WPA2

Comment: I have update my answer, a WEP key is supposed weak and unsecured

Comment: In addition, it's also possible to use `wpa_cli` to add networks from the command line or in a script if this is more convenient than making a configuration file. `wpa_cli help` lists the commands (more than mentioned in the documentation).

Comment: It's my first time getting a chance to test but I'm at Starbucks so I can only test with no password. Here is the result of the script https://pastebin.com/9Z2E5VTK I disconnect but never get running. Is it possible I need to add a line to stop any previous instances of `wpa_supplicant` before starting?

Comment: @PhilipKirkbride `rm /run/wpa_supplicant/wlo1` then `killall wpa_supplicant` as the ouptut error say . What is the content of `connect.sh` script?

Comment: I will try that `connect.sh` is the first code block in your answer.

Comment: To use an open network , write the configuration manully and remove the tow lines `wep_key0` and `wep_tx_keyidx` following the wpa_supplicant.conf on my answer

Comment: I'm having an issue with the step `i=$(iw dev | grep Interface | awk '{ print $2}')` because when I run `sudo iw dev` I get no output.

Comment: What is the expected output of `iw dev` maybe I can get it somewhere else.

Comment: @PhilipKirkbride How many wifi interfaces did you have?

Comment: @GAD3R just one, I found people on Pi having a similar issue using `iw` https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/39601/make-iw-work-on-raspbian I can use `iwlist` but not `iw` for some reason. Opened another question related https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/401413/iw-dev-interface-scan-not-working-on-embedded-device

Comment: @GAD3R what should the result of `i=$(iw dev | grep Interface | awk '{ print $2}')` be? I'm going to see if I can find another way around it.

Comment: it should return : `wlan3`

Comment: @GAD3R I was able to replace it with this `i=$(ifconfig -a | grep wl | cut -d' ' -f1)` going to try again.

Comment: @GAD3R running `sudo wpa_supplicant -i wlan3 -c/etc/wpa_supplicant/wpa_supplicant.conf -B` returns `Successfully initialized wpa_supplicant` and `wlan3: Failed to initialize driver interface`

Answer (score 1):

I ended up replacing my script with this. Seems to work on my system and keeps the original structure.

```
wifi=$(cat /proc/net/wireless | perl -ne '/(\w+):/ && print $1')

if [ -n "$2" ];then
  iwconfig $wifi essid "$1" key "s:$2"
else
  iwconfig $wifi essid "$1" key
fi

dhclient $wifi
```

Comment: This will not work for WPA, only for WEP. I strongly recommend against using WEP, it's broken.

Comment: WEP is broken as in "people will break the password and look at your traffic or use your AP"

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Wicd](http://wicd.sourceforge.net/), it has a command line and GUI interface for managing your wifi networking. I have used it for a while, as a lightweight alternative to NM. It will save you of having to deal with `wpa_supplicant` manually.